# Redirect users to the last page visited, after login from component

Tags: joomla-3.4, user

In Joomla 3.5.1, I want to redirect users to the page they were before logging in.

If they login from mod_login, no problem, since the module is pending from the top menu, they just stay at that page.

The problem happens when the users login from the component: they are always redirected to the profile page.

In the menu item `index.php?option=com_users&view=login` there's an option to redirect users after login.

But how do I tell: "`Get them back to the page they were before`"?

Certain components are appending something like:

```
?return=L2YlQzMlQjNydW0tcGVyZ3VudGFzLWUtcmVzcG9zdGFzL2NvbnZlcnNhdGi9yZWFkLmh0bWw/aWQ9MjU=
```

To the URL, requesting a redirect to a specific page.

But they always go back to the profile page.

Comment: `they always go back to the profile page.` it happens to me, regardless of modifying as @Lodder suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simple to do this.

You will firstly need to create a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the following file:

```
components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
```

Once done, open the following file (your override):

```
templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default_login.php
```

and go to line 81, where you will see the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
```

and replace it with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); ?>" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 Very nice idea. I'm not sure if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is always a valid choice, but I like the idea .

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos - Yeah it does have some [drawbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6880668/1362108). A more advanced and reliable solution would involve a system plugin, making use of a session or cookie

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, I've been using template overrides for K2 for years but for core joomla it seems impossible. I did look at the instructions in your link, including the "Creating overrides" section but whatever changes I do are ignored.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - The file you open to make the changes to, does the path match what I've provided in my answer (2nd code snippet)? It should be exactly the same, apart from `MY_TEMPLATE` which of course is the name of your template

Comment: @NunoNogueira - I made a mistake with the path, I've updated it now. (remove `/view/`)

Comment: @Lodder A-Ha!, now the override is effecting. It is redirecting the users to the page before loggin in! But it's not working when users are logging in from an URL with the suffix:  ?return=XXXXXXXXX. I'm going to ask another question.

Comment: Something is wrong with me... I change line 81 with above code. To show that I'm modifying in the right file, I put `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` on top of page, and it is displayed. But always after login, it redirects to profile page...

Answer (score 0):

Do not create any login menu.  This way it redirects automatically to the last page requested and attempts to login. For the same page, then use a guest page to a restricted page or you can use a login redirect to the same page.